# How do I install PyQt4 on Anaconda version 4.3.X

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, anaconda, pyqt5

I'm trying to downgrade my current version of PyQt5 to PyQt4 temporarily. However, this command `conda install pyqt=4.11` only yields this error.

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pyqt 4.11* -> python 2.7*
  - python 3.6*
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use: `conda info pyqt=4`

You can see which Python Versions are working.
At the moment, the latest Python3 working with pyqt4 is 3.5

Now:

```
# Create new environment with python 3.5
conda create -n py35_qt4 python=3.5 anaconda

# Activate the new environment
activate py35_qt4

# Remove pyqt5
conda remove pyqt

# Install the PyQt4 package in the new environment
conda install pyqt=4
```

Answer (score -1):

PyQt4 only works with Python 2, while PyQt5 only work with Python 3. You are probably trying to install PyQt4 in a Python 3 environment. I recommend you to create a new anaconda environment with Python 2 and then install PyQt4.

Comment: Anaconda 4.1.1 uses Python 3.5.3, and it is using PyQt 4.11.